# Reference a dataframe column that is named with a reserved word

Tags: r, dataframe

I have just imported data where one of the column names is "repeat."  If I try to reference the column via `data$repeat`, I get an error `Error: unexpected 'repeat' in "data$repeat".`  The same problem happens when I reference `repeat` inside of a linear regression.

How can I reference a column with a reserved word in order to either change the column or use it in a linear regression?

```
data <- data.frame('repeat' = 1, 'break' = 2, check.names = FALSE)
data

#   repeat break
# 1      1     2

data$repeat
```

> Error: unexpected 'repeat' in "data$repeat"

Comment: Are you importing with `read.table`?

Comment: quotes or backticks?

Comment: For future users, if you're trying to reference `repeat` as part of a list of covariates in a regression, using backticks will not work, but quotes do work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this syntax to select column `"repeat"`:

```
data$`repeat`
```

Answer (score 3):

Use the column selection syntax

```
data[, "repeat"]
```

This is also useful when you want to use a variable as column name.